# Show that weak local minimum of a convex function $\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is its weak global minimum.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Show that weak local minimum of a convex function $\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is its weak global minimum. Does the same happen to strong minimums?

I know that when $f$ is convex, then we have $f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\le (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)$

for $\lambda\in[0,1], x,y \in \mathbb{R}^N$

But how can i move any further?

Comment: Sorry, I found it already on p. 418 of http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-13.pdf

Comment: What is a weak local minimum?

Comment: non-strict local minimum